# Loop sound in AS2

Tags: audio, actionscript-2

When a song is finished playing in Flash, it usually stops and never plays again unless you refresh the page. How would I make it restart (or "loop") using ActionScript 2.0?

This is the code so far:

```
song = new Sound(); 
song.loadSound("Madeon - Finale.mp3", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
song = new Sound(); 
song.loadSound( "Madeon - Finale.mp3", true );

song.onLoad = function( success:Boolean )
{ 
    if (success)
    { 
        song.start(); 
    }
    else
    { 
        // fail 
    }
}

// replay
song.onSoundComplete = function()
{
    song.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick option:

```
song = new Sound(); 
song.loadSound("Madeon - Finale.mp3", true);
song.start(0,999);
```

Where the song loops `999` times.